# Cant fill DataSet but MySqlCommand works properly

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, dataset, sqlexception

So I am not able to fill a DataSet. I get the following Exception:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server.
>
> The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections.
>
> (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1326)

But with the same ConnectionString I am able to execute a query using the MySqlCommand class.

This here works:

```
var con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"];
_helper = new MySqlHelper(con.ConnectionString);
string query = "SELECT Bezeichnung FROM stationen";
var reader = _helper.ExecuteReader(query);
while(reader.Read())
{
    //do something
}
```

But if I use DataSets, I get the error when trying to fill the DataSet

```
var con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"];
string query = "SELECT Bezeichnung FROM stationen";

using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con.ConnectionString))
{
    var dataset = new U2ZFDataSet();
    adapter.Fill(dataset, "stationen");
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is the DataSet not working properly?

Also, here is the MySqlHelpter code:

```
private MySqlConnection _connection;

public MySqlHelper(string connectionString)
{
    try
    {
        _connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        _connection.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (_connection != null)
        {
            _connection.Dispose();
            _connection = null;
        }

        throw new Exception(connectionString, ex);
    }
}

public MySqlDataReader ExecuteReader(string sqlString)
{
    try
    {
        if (_connection == null || _connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            throw new Exception("Connection closed");

        using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sqlString, _connection))
        {
            return command.ExecuteReader();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(sqlString, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: put `MySqlHelper` code here

Comment: @AliAdlavaran I have edited my question

Comment: where is initialization of the ` _connection`? put the code

Comment: I have added the initialization of _connection aswell

Comment: i'm looking for 'MySqlCommand' ! I need to see it :)

Comment: where is the open connection in the case of the dataset the connection open happens in the helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open the connection before using the `SqlDataAdapter`. In the first example you use the helper, which is doing this for you but in the second case you don't use the helper anymore.

```
var con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"];
string query = "SELECT Bezeichnung FROM stationen";

con.Open();

using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con.ConnectionString))
{
    var dataset = new U2ZFDataSet();
    adapter.Fill(dataset, "stationen");
}

con.Close() -- do not forget to close it as well
```

Check this example [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter).

It would be better if you would wrap the connection opening in a `try-catch` block, just like you do in the helper class.